# Using a switch to map function pointers to strings

Tags: c, enums

I'm working on a network service that based on commands it receives over the network, it has workers perform different jobs. I want to have a log entry for every time a certain worker is tasked with doing some job.

I have a function (say `function_caller`) which, among other things, calls another function which it receives its pointer as an argument. I'd like to have my logger notify what kind of function `function_caller` calls.

Originally I wanted the `function_caller` to receive some enum instead of a function pointer, provide the enum to the logger, and then use a helper function which returns a suitable pointer based on the enum. However, `function_caller` is already deeply tangled in the codebase I'm working on, and it looks like it would be a lot of work to refactor all the functions that call `function_caller` to choose the right enum and use a new argument.

So my next idea was having a `switch` that for every function pointer will have some string representation of, but I've never stumbled upon something like that (and struggled to find anyone even mentioning such an idea on Google), so I have a feeling I might be missing some serious downsides to this option.

The only significant problem I see is that every developer that decides to pass a new kind of function pointer to `function_caller` will have to somehow know to update the `switch`, otherwise it will fail.

Am I missing anything else? Or maybe there's some other approach I should consider?

Comment: `switch` is only specified to work with integral types or `enum` types.   It can't be used for any pointer type.

Comment: What I had in mind was casting it to `intptr_t`.

Comment: @Thomas the question is tagged C, not C++

Comment: Why do you want to log a function name ? Why not logging the function address ? Then you can find the function in the map file, either manually or automatically with for example a small python program (that would link the function addresses and their name in the map file)

Comment: Can you provide some sort of usage example since this is all quite vague?

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean
@Lundin The program in question is a network service that based on commands it receives over the network, it has workers perform different jobs. I want to have a log entry for every time a certain worker is tasked with doing some job (a job being that function that `function_caller` calls). Having the log contain some address isn't very practical for the administrator in charge of monitoring the service.

Comment: @GabeL You can cast the function pointer to `intptr_t` to use it in `switch(...)` but you cannot use the function pointers as `case` labels because they are not constants. Depending on how exactly you call `function_caller` you could rename it to e.g. `function_caller_internal`, add a string argument for the function name and replace it with a wrapper macro `function caller` that stringifies the function name. Or simply log the service command.

Comment: @GabeL You should [edit] your question and add all background information instead of writing it in comments.

Comment: You might consider having your logger inspect the stack trace to determine which function was called.  However, I think you're probably over-complicating the problem.  I suggest adding a trace function, or call to your logger, in each function in question.

Comment: Why not have people pass a function pointer *and* a human readable name together? Easy, works every time everywhere, impossible to forget or mess up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace `function_caller` with a wrapper macro of the same name that calls the renamed function `function_caller_internal` which gets an additional string argument. The wrapper macro can then pass an additional stringified function name.

This works only if `function_caller` is always called with a function name, not a function pointer variable.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void funcA(void)
{
  printf("This is funcA\n");
}

static void funcB(void)
{
  printf("This is funcB\n");
}

/* renamed function gets an additional string argument */
static void function_caller_internal(void (*func)(void), const char *name)
{
   printf("calling %s\n", name);
   func();
}

/* wrapper macro stringifies the function name to pass it the additional argument */
#define function_caller(func) function_caller_internal(func, #func)

int main(void)
{
   /* unchanged calls */
   function_caller(funcA);
   function_caller(funcB);
   return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
calling funcA
This is funcA
calling funcB
This is funcB
```

Answer (score 4):

How about something like this? Instead of a switch, store a table of functions and their name strings. The table can even be kept dynamically updated, unlike a switch case. You will not need to walk along the edge of the standard as well!

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*callback_t) (void);

void first (void) { printf("%d", 1); };
void second (void) { printf("%d", 2); };
void third (void) { printf("%d", 3); };

typedef struct fntable_t
{
    callback_t fn;
    char *name;
} fntable_t;

fntable_t fntable[] =
{
    { first, "first" },
    { second, "second" },
    { third, "third" }
};

char* log_str(callback_t c)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(fntable) / sizeof(fntable_t); i++)
    {
        if(fntable[i].fn == c)
            return fntable[i].name;    
    }
    return "unknown";
}

void function_caller(callback_t c)
{
    printf("%s",log_str(c));
    c();
}

int main(void) 
{
    function_caller(first);
    function_caller(second);
    function_caller(third);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can change the API of the functions, then consider using `__func__` to get the textual name of each function. If you can have a function pointer type along the lines of this:

```
typedef void func_t (const char** name);
```

Then you can have each function return its name to the caller.

```
void foo (const char** name)
{
  /* do foo stuff here */
  *name = __func__;
}

void bar (const char** name)
{
  /* do bar stuff here */
  *name = __func__;
}
```

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void func_t (const char** name);

void foo (const char** name)
{
  /* do foo stuff here */
  *name = __func__;
}

void bar (const char** name)
{
  /* do bar stuff here */
  *name = __func__;
}

const char* function_caller (func_t* func, const char** name)
{
  func(name);
  return *name;
}

int main(void)
{
  static func_t*const func [] = 
  {
    foo,
    bar,
  };
  const char* name;

  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof func/sizeof *func; i++)
  {
    puts( function_caller(func[i], &name) );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, I didn't know this `__func__` stuff

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your codebase has sane variable names and function names, you can add a `char *` argument to your function caller:

```
void function_caller(char *name, int fpnt());
```

and then provide a macro:

```
#define function_caller_autoname(fpnt) function_caller(#fpnt, fpnt)
```

(Or, for spaghetti code, you can provide a macro with the same name as the function).

The `#fpnt` will be expanded by the proceprocessor to a string literal with the function name.

Then when your codebase called:

```
function_caller(some_function)
```

refactor it to:

```
function_caller_autoname(some_function)
# will be expanded to by the processor:
# function_caller("some_function", some_function)
```

or refactor it manually to provide the name/identificator/description of the function:

```
function_caller("Some function: ", some_function)
```

That way you can pass a custom string that describes the function along with the pointer. Also, each developer can pass a custom description string.